# How to find greatest set intersection of at least a given cardinality?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, combinatorics

While dealing with a problem, I uncovered this subproblem:

Input: A set of sets $S = \{S_1,...,S_r\}$ where $\mid$ $S_1$ $\cup$ ... $\cup$ $S_r$$\mid = n$, as well as a number $k<n$.

Output: A subset of $S$, $T = \{S_{t_{1}},...,S_{t_{p}}\}$ so that $\mid$ $S_{t_{1}}$ $\cap$ ... $\cap$ $S_{t_{p}}$$\mid$ $\geq k$ with $p=\mid T \mid$ maximized.

I.e. find the greatest number of sets in $S$ whose intersection preserves at least $k$ elements.

Is there any way of solving this problem in reasonable time, say polynomial in $r$ and $n$?

I tried to create an algorithm to solve the problem in reasonable time for large sets and $n$ and got nowhere. There's the obvious brute force algorithm that runs in $n2^r$ time. I also tried to construct a DP algorithm that used smaller subsets for optimal substructure, i.e. making use of $(A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap B \cap C$ and that if $\mid A \cap B \mid < k$, then it's not worth searching any further with $A\cap B$. However, I didn't get anywhere since the number of different subsets grows too quickly.

On the one hand, the problem feels kind of "set coverish" and thus I suspect it's hard. On the other, I'd imagine a problem this simple to be mentioned in some list of hard problems if it were intractable.

Comment: I believe that's the maximal bipartite clique problem, or a subset of it, due to specifying k.

Comment: reading the introduction of the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03003330 it seems that the maximum vertex biclique problem is strongly related to the question, and as the authors state "the problem [the maximum vertex biclique problem] can be solved in polynomial time via the matching algorithm."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to reduce clique to your problem. Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and a number $\ell$, for each vertex $x$ let
$$
S_x = \left\{\{y,z\} \in \binom{V}{2} : y,z \neq x\right\} \cup \{ \{x,y\} : \{x,y\} \in E \}.
$$
In words, $S_x$ contains all edges in the graph touching $x$, and all edges not touching $x$, whether or not they're in the graph.

One can then show that for every set of vertices $A$,
$$
\bigcap_{x \in A} S_x = \left\{\{y,z\} \in \binom{V}{2} : y,z \notin A\right\} \cup \{ \{x,y\} : x \in A \text{ and } \{x,y\} \in E \}.
$$
In words, the intersection of $S_x$ for $x \in A$ consists of all edges in the graph touching $A$, as well as all edges not touching $A$ (whether in the graph or not). The size of this intersection reaches its maximum $\binom{|V|-|A|}{2} + \binom{|A|}{2}$ if and only if $A$ is a clique in the graph.

Choosing $k = \binom{|V|-\ell}{2} + \binom{\ell}{2}$, the graph contains an $\ell$-clique if and only if there are $p=\ell$ sets whose intersection contains at least $k$ points. The value of $n$ for this instance is $n = \binom{|V|}{2}$.